# AWS - MySQL connection

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, ef-code-first, entity, identity

I'm having a little problem when run an code at an AWS Windows VM, I can't connect to an AWS MySQL insance from it. Here is my Checklist:

- Opened the ports at MySQL;
- Opened the ports at Windows VM;
- The application runs at my local machine;

And here is the stacktrace:

```
2017-08-06 22:14:33.2758|ERROR|ServerApp.Service.Logging|System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for MySQL: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) (C:\Program Files (x86)\ServerApp\ServerApp.exe.Config line 6) ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at System.Configuration.TypeUtil.GetTypeWithReflectionPermission(IInternalConfigHost host, String typeString, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.Init(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
   at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.InitWithRestrictedPermissions(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
   at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.CreateSectionFactory(FactoryRecord factoryRecord)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration.get_Settings()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager.IsReplicationGroup(String groupName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   at MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
```

What am I missing???

Comment: "Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. " sounds to me like a dependencies problem?

Comment: The problem is: only when I upload this application to an AWS VM that error occur. And I cant access my RDS from any app at the AWS.

Comment: But you are able to access RDS from your local machine? In that case, this would be not a problem with RDS, but with what is installed on the VM in AWS.

Comment: @LechMigdal yes, I enabled all type of access to both services, RDS and EC2

Comment: Does it mean that the app works fine from e.g. you local environment with the RDS instance as the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password has an `&` and the Windows Server 2016 doesn't recognise it.